# Reset a loop in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Basically If somebody presses `button2` then I want the program to reset the measuring. The actually code keeps measuring forever and I only want to reset that measuring. Sorry for my bad english, I hope you understand what I really want, If not I will explain in details.

Here is my code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private MonitorWidth As Double = 51.5 'cm 
    Private MonitorHeigth As Double = 31 'cm - This must be enter by the user
    Private TotalDistance As Double
    Private PixelHeigth As Double 'cm
    Private PixelWidth As Double 'cm
    Private WithEvents TTimer As New Timers.Timer
    Private PointQueue As New Queue(Of Point)(100)
    Private Lastpoint As Point

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

        TTimer.Stop()

        While PointQueue.Count > 0
            Dim P As Point = PointQueue.Dequeue
            TotalDistance += Math.Sqrt(((Lastpoint.X - P.X) * PixelWidth) ^ 2 + ((Lastpoint.Y - P.Y) * PixelHeigth) ^ 2)
            Lastpoint = P

            TextBox1.Text = Format(TotalDistance, "Distance: #,##0.0 cm")
            TTimer.Start()

        End While

    End Sub

    Private Sub TTimer_Elapsed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs) Handles TTimer.Elapsed
        PointQueue.Enqueue(MousePosition)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        If Button1.Enabled = True Then

            Lastpoint = MousePosition
            TTimer.AutoReset = True
            TTimer.Interval = 5
            TTimer.Start()
            Dim ScreenBounds As Rectangle = Screen.GetBounds(New Point(0, 0))
            Dim Screenwidth_Pixel As Integer = ScreenBounds.Width
            Dim screenHeigth_Pixel As Integer = ScreenBounds.Height
            PixelHeigth = MonitorHeigth / screenHeigth_Pixel
            PixelWidth = MonitorWidth / Screenwidth_Pixel
            Timer1.Interval = 200
            Timer1.Start()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        If Button2.Enabled = True Then

            Timer1.Stop()
            TextBox1.Text = ""
            TextBox1.Text = Format(TotalDistance = 0)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: try using a global variable that resets when you click on the button

Answer (score 1):

In your `Button2` event handler (`Button2_Click`), reset the queue:

```
PointQueue = New Queue(Of Point)(100)
```

Comment: I've just pasted this code in the button2 and its not working, the measuring resumes, it don't start from 0

Comment: @SuoraAnne - I have assumed your `PointQueue` is where the measurements are held. The above code resets to an empty queue. Where did you paste it? Did you debug and check that this line executes?

Comment: @SuoraAnne - Yes, you have shown that event handler. But did you paste this inside the `If`? And you didn't answer my question about debugging through.

Comment: Yes I have pasted the code inside the If. And I also checked and it appears that the line executes.

Comment: @SuoraAnne - Great. And my assumption that the `PrintQueue` is where you hold your measurements is correct or not? What variable do you need to set to 0?